# understanding default usage of `pylab.legend`

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am using pylab to produce this image:
[image: Image with messed up legend]

where the legend is not what I wanted. The dots represent actual data points, the lines are made with polyfit. I would like the legend to contain either ten entries with the lines and dots merged together for each color or just the ten dot-lines.

The associated piece of code:

```
for i in range(start, start + size*chunks):
    colorVal = scalarMap.to_rgba(values[i])
    slc1, slc2 = start + i*size, start + (i+1)*size
    mylegend.append(" = ".join([self.dtypes[v1],
                              "%.2f" %data[v1, slc1]]))
    jx = data[x, slc1:slc2]
    jy = data[y, slc1:slc2]
    p  = np.polyfit(jx, jy, deg = 2)
    lx = np.linspace(jx[0], jx[-1], 1000)
    ly = p[0]*lx**2 + p[1]*lx + p[2]
    pl.plot(jx, jy, "o", color = colorVal)
    pl.plot(lx, ly, color = colorVal)
pl.xlabel(self.dtypes[x])
pl.ylabel(self.dtypes[y])
pl.title(title)
pl.axis(axis)
pl.legend(my_legend, loc = "upper left", shadow = True)
pl.grid("on")
pl.show()
```

I realize what the mistake is: I add ten points to the my_legend list, and the legend function of pylab is then reading from it until the list ends. Therefore, only half of them make it. However, I don't know how to fix it. Is there a way I can make the legend function only register one entry for each iteration of the loop?

Also, I would like the points listed in reverse order. I tried

```
pl.legend(my_legend[::-1])
```

but that didn't work.

Any ideas to these two issues?

Comment: As point out by Francesco, matplotlib did _exactly_ what you told it to.  You should change the title to be less inflammatory and more descriptive to aid future users.

Comment: Well, yes, as I wrote, I did understand what the error was, I just didn't know how to fix it. English not being my first language, I thought the title was anything but inflammatory, but if it is perceived as such, Ill change it. Would "How can I filter the contents of pylab's legend?" be a better title in your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of `pylab.legend` is appropriated, once you understand how does it work. When you call `pylab.legend(my_legend, ...)`, the list of strings of the labels is associated to the first 10 lines drawn. The way you do, the first 10 lines are the one added in the first 5 loops.
To show just the dots you can do this:

```
for i in range(start, start + size*chunks):
    [...]
    label = " = ".join([self.dtypes[v1], "%.2f" %data[v1, slc1]])
    [...]
    pl.plot(jx, jy, "o", color = colorVal, label=label)
    pl.plot(lx, ly, color = colorVal)

[...]
pl.legend(loc = "upper left", shadow = True)
```

If you want the legend for the lines, you just put the `label=label` into the other plot command.

An alternative approach is to create a `mylines` list (similar to `mylegend`) and to append just one of the plot command and then call the `pl.legend(mylines, mylegend, ...)`